# Unable to choose account to share docs from

Tags: gmail, file-sharing

Started using this new Samsung S9 a week or so ago and it has an annoying trait/bug in Gmail that my older S6 Edge/S5 never had.

If I choose a document or photo, from any app, to share, the system always choose the same e-mail account and the drop-down menu for my other two accounts is inactive. However, if I use any of these accounts via Gmail first, the drop-down menus appear, showing all three Gmail accounts. I can't figure this out.

Any ideas? The latest update didn't sort it either.

Comment: Update: this issue is not with Gmail. I just tried to share a web page and when Gmail opened I managed to get all of my Gmail e-addresses. So, this issue is an Android issue. I checked Gallery Apps permissions and it is allowed to search for accounts.

Comment: Can I just check exactly what happens? You have a document open in another app, you click "Share with..." and choose Gmail, and then from Gmail's compose window, the thing for switching accounts is inactive. But if you open Gmail directly, you can change accounts just fine. Is that right?

Comment: That's correct, Dan.

Answer (score 0):

Right, for some unknown reason (no obvious updates, either) the drop-down email addressed are now visible when sharing from an app itself! Weird!

Sorted!